# Why is Safari locking up when creating a large Float32Array?

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I am trying to convert a large Float32Array to an Array in javascript with the following:

```
buffer = new Float32Array(60000);
data = Array.prototype.slice.call(buffer);
```

It works just fine in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari (Version 6.0.4) locks up.  I have discovered that simply:

```
new Float32Array(60000);
```

also locks up Safari.  "Locks up" here means that the current page/tab (or console) becomes unresponsive and it never returns.

Why is Safari locking up?  Is this a bug?  What is the fastest way to convert a large Float32Array into an Array as fast as possible in all 3 browsers?

Comment: Which version of Safari? It didn't support typed arrays until version 5.1.

Comment: "locks up" as in the browser stops responding to any input of any kind and never recovers, or...?

Comment: Version 6.0.4 - see above.

Comment: "Locks up" - means that the current page/tab becomes indefinitely unresponsive.